# How to use MediaSessionCompat?

Tags: android, media, android-appcompat

How do I use a MediaSessionCompat?  Can someone give a simple working example?

I've found some, but they use:

```
MediaSessionCompat _mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "tag");
```

This gives me error:
`The constructor MediaSessionCompat(Context, String) is undefined` and wants me to use `MediaSessionCompat(Context, String, ComponentName, PendingIntent)`

Answer (score 2):

I found a working example here, which I tested both on kitkat and marshmallow.

https://github.com/tutsplus/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/backgroundaudio/BackgroundAudioService.java

But do take note, sometimes, sometimes lock screen control don't appear because of android settings(i.e Settings > Sounds & Notifications > Notification > While Locked > Hide Sensitive Content) See below:

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Android/Android-Lollipop-Lock-Screen-Controls-Not-Available/td-p/982463

Comment: I had tested your demo in github. In nexus6p, if you play music firstly, then switch to home page. At this time, you cannot pause the music in my bt headset. App can receive key event, but It is KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY. I don't know why this can happen and how to fix it. Can you help me about this?
the log: 
onMediaButtonEvent()keycode: 126 key: 0 active: true

Answer (score 1):

`MediaSessionCompat` is in `android.support.v4` and that is the [Constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#MediaSessionCompat%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ComponentName,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) it uses.. it is a backward compatibility for `MediaSession` introduced in api 21, and this is its [Constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html#MediaSession%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29);. However if you want to use the Constructor you are referring to you need to compile your project with api 21+;

Comment: @Gintas_ Do you have a working example with MediaSessionCompat for SDK < 21? I'm stuck there too...

Comment: @kodingralph I don't have it yet

Answer (score 1):

SampleMediaRouterActivity.java in Support7Demos seems to be a good place to start.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/media/

Comment: the link is dead