# How can I use MediaSessionManager in Android API 16?

Tags: java, android, audio, media, android-appcompat

```
import android.media.session.MediaSessionManager;

  private MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
  mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
```

It requires minimum api level 21. But I've to used in api level 16

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to make your code easier to read.

Comment: Perhaps using the App compat version. This [answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586477/556600)